# Game Lobby in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a mobile game on various mobile platforms and have decided to use PHP/MySQL as the back end and communicate with this via JSON. (The game will be text based).

I'm lacking on idea's on how to implement this, the sort of logic i'm after is as follows;

- User will need to register an account
- User will enter the game lobby looking for an open slot
- If there is a suitable game ready and waiting (not full and waiting for new players) then join
- If not create a new game and await players

I was thinking of having 20 players for each game and only allowing the game to start when there's 3 or more players waiting. When there's 3 or more players waiting there would be a count down of say 60 seconds until the game began.

Now i know some of this might need to be done on the client side. I'm struggling on where to start!! So any idea's, code samples or links to reading material that may help would be very much appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: Important note: **NONE** of it (as far as limitations) should be performed client side (clients are easily interfered with). The server should handle any thresholds or throttling, and the client just re-affirms/follows along. _unless of course you don't care that much_ -- P.S. Please work on that acceptance rating (including marking or answering past answers).

Comment: @BradChristie: Err, past edit threshold: past _questions_*

Comment: thanks for the reminder of answering past questions, i had completely forgotten and there was some good answers! Thanks for the input!

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?  There's a lot you're asking for here, and the code to actually achieve everything you've got planned is going to be long, complex, and split into multiple files.

Comment: I'm not after code, i just can't get my head around where to start!! the part i can't grasp is the logic for each game. i.e a game waits for players and when it's full create a new game etc.

Comment: @Nathan: Sounds like you need to look at making a database schema first. Setup how you're saving player info, how you're storing the queue, the active games, the delays, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments, I'm guessing you're looking for some ideas on database schema, like Brad Christie suggests.  So I'm going to start with that.

First, you'll need a table for the players.  I'm guessing you already have one of those, but you'll probably want to include a field for the game ID that they're in.

Next, you'll need a table for the games.  This is where you store information on the game itself, including whether it's active.  To get the player count, you simply query the list of players with that game's ID.  You could also keep track of player count and update it whenever the player leaves or joins the game, depending on a few factors.

Now, the game lobby itself.  The exact method here really depends on how you want it to function.  You can either use AJAX to keep a list of currently active games up to date (and set up some sort of chat system to let players talk while waiting), or you can use the game lobby as routing page.  If you go the latter route, then query the active games, automatically dump the player into one that meets your criteria, then send the user to the 'main game page'.

Hopefully this will give you a solid outline on how to start.  I'm afraid I can't help you much more unless I know more about your requirements.

Comment: thats the exact sort of answer i was looking for! I'll reply in greater detail when i'm home from work. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For register a user you simply need a form and save that form in your database. When the user logs in the you query the database matching the password and user name.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I'm already able to do the authentication side of things, it was more the other logic i was after.